# Issue with System.Threading.Timer and Modal ShowDialog()

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, timer

I have an application, wherein a class I am initializing a `Windows Form` and a `System.Threading.Timer`.

If the `timer`, which keeps checking for some `IPC`based stuff, encounters a particular value, it signals an `event` in the same class, which then calls `ShowDialog()` on the dialog initialized earlier.

Unfortunately, this `ShowDialog()` being `Modal`, stops the timer.

I had the impression that `System.Threaded.Timer` was created in a different thread to the calling thread and so the Timer would continue to run in the background.

**Edit - some code**

```
public delegate void EventHandler();
class someClass
{
    WrapperForm dlg = null;
    public void CallToChildThread(Object stateInfo)
    {
        AutoResetEvent autoEvent = (AutoResetEvent)stateInfo;
        //Check IPC
        //Fire event
        _show.Invoke();
    }
    public someClass()
    {
        public static event EventHandler _show;
        initializeDialog(); // Initialize the dialog. Standard new
        var autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        var stateTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(CallToChildThread,
                                   autoEvent, 1000, 250);
        _show += new EventHandler(eventCheck);
    }
    void eventCheck()
    {
        //If some condition
        dlg.ShowDialog(); //Timer stops
    }
}
```

How could this be resolved?

Comment: If you could let us see what you have tried (some code) that'd be great.

Comment: A modal does not halt a timer for me o.O

Comment: I made some changes so reflect your code, I hope it helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class `System.Threading.Timer` has a known issue where if you do not keep a reference to it it can be collected by the garbage collector even when running.

Switch to using `System.Timers.Timer` which is just a wrapper around `System.Threading.Timer` or keep a reference to the timer so the GC does not collect it and cancel your timer.

```
public delegate void EventHandler();
class someClass
{
    WrapperForm dlg = null;
    System.Threading.Timer stateTimer;
    public static event EventHandler _show;

    public void CallToChildThread(Object stateInfo)
    {
        AutoResetEvent autoEvent = (AutoResetEvent)stateInfo;
        //Check IPC
        //Fire event
        _show.Invoke();
    }
    public someClass()
    {
        initializeDialog(); // Initialize the dialog. Standard new
        var autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        stateTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(CallToChildThread,
                                   autoEvent, 1000, 250);
        _show += new EventHandler(eventCheck);
    }
    void eventCheck()
    {
        //If some condition
        dlg.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah, this was the priblem. Replacing it with `System.Timers.Timer` did the trick. Thank you. Is the issue with `System.Threading.Timer` commonly known?

Answer (score 1):

With your code I changed my example, I am using your timer now (I'm still using my timer so I can see the other timer is still running)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Form frm1 = new Form();
        int i;
        private System.Threading.Timer t;
        //If the problem is garbage collecting then the line above is very important.
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            var autoEvent = new AutoResetEvent(false);
            var stateTimer = new System.Threading.Timer(CallToChildThread,
                                   autoEvent, 1000, 250);
        }
    private void CallToChildThread(object state)
    {
        i++;
        //Updating value here, update in other timer (this is to avoid crossthreadEx)   
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        frm1.ShowDialog();
        //Label keeps updating!
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        label1.Text = i.ToString();
    }
}
```

It still works for me, the reason might be because I did not make timer a local variable, instead declared it in the class.

Comment: You are using the wrong kind of timer for your test, System.Threading.Timer does not have a `Tick` event, it uses delegate callbacks.

Comment: I have added some code. System.Threading.Timer does not have an Enabled property.